# How can I encode and decode a string with a simple passphrase in PHP?

Tags: php, decode, encode, encryption

I thought this would be simple but I can't find a simple solution to this..

Is there a way to encode a string and decode a string with a simple passphrase?
somesthing like this:

```
$encoded = stringEncrypt('someText','simpleKey');
echo stringDecrypt($encoded,'simpleKey'); //outputs someText;
```

I tried this but with no luck:

```
function lime_encrypt($data,$key)
{
    return base_convert(bin2hex($data),16,10)  *   base_convert(bin2hex($key),16,10)  ;
}

function lime_decrypt($data,$key)
{
    return pack("H*",base_convert($data/base_convert(bin2hex($key),16,10),10,16));
}
```

I think this is because the multiplication doesn't returns a integer but a mathematical expression 6.28414834514E+25

any idea how I can implement this?

---

### edit

I reused another code I found on stack overflow and ended up with this:

```
function lime_encrypt($data,$key)
{
    return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
}

function lime_decrypt($data,$key)
{
    return rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($data), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");
}
```

but I end up with a Fatal error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_encrypt() using php > 5 on linux centOS.

So I'd rather stay simple and movable to other hostings...

---

### Solution?

At the end, I'm using this, found on a blog:

```
function lime_encrypt($data,$key)
{
    return openssl_encrypt($data, 'AES-128-CBC', $key,0,'fgrgfvcfghtfdrfg');
}

function lime_decrypt($data,$key)
{
    return openssl_decrypt($data, 'AES-128-CBC', $key,0,'fgrgfvcfghtfdrfg');
}
```

Comment: Why does it need to be simple? Would a suggestion that actually employs Password Bases Encryption (as defined in PKCS#5) not be sufficient?

Comment: md5 encryption should be fine for what you need

Comment: @ScottFiander because I can't go 2way with md5, neither put a custom passphrase

Comment: @ScottFiander md5 encryption does not exist (and if you mean performing md5 to derive a key, it is insecure by itself)

Comment: @owlstead I'm very new into this

Comment: @VincentDuprez Normally you first derive a symmetric key with using a one way function (md5 is one way, but it is a bit too simple, normally PBKDF2 is used). Then you encrypt/decrypt with the resulting key.\

Comment: @owlstead like the edit I placed or do you mean something else?

Comment: @VincentDuprez Well, it does not use key derivation and it uses a static IV, but it is almost certainly an upgrade. I'll try and find a better solution, but I must say that PHP does not feature too many good examples of cryptography. Check out [this page](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/hash_pbkdf2).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to encode a string and decode a string with a simple passphrase?

Check out [defuse/php-encryption](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption). Specifically, the [`KeyProtectedByPassword`](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption/blob/master/docs/classes/KeyProtectedByPassword.md) feature.

If you're on PHP 7.2, you can also use a combination of `sodium_crypto_pwhash()` and `sodium_crypto_secretbox()` (with `base64_encode()`) to achieve a congruent (but not interoperable) result.